# What exactly is the use of flush for a printwriter object?

Tags: java, io, printwriter

I'm looking for a theoretical analysis. I mean, how does the buffer system works and what advantage does using flush provide? Kindly illustrate with an example, if possible.

Comment: Here is a helpful link.
Visit http://www.coderanch.com/t/522900/java/java/flush-Java

Comment: Why do you need a theoretical analysis, just have a look at the source. It is more a practical question. flush() is only good in 2 situations: if you want to circumvent buffering for latency reasons or if you want to do anything to the underlying streams and need to be sure the data arrived. (both most often only valid if you use sockets or fsync). You especially never need to flush() if you are sure you write more immediatelly (i.e. in a loop).

Answer (score 12):

When you are writing to a text file, `BufferedWriter` does not write it to disk immediately. Instead, it keeps the data in a buffer in memory.

This has the advantage that many small writes will go into the buffer, and then the data will be written to disk in one go, ie. with one big write, instead of many small writes, which would be inefficient.

When the buffer is full, `BufferedWriter` will write the data out on it's own, ie. it will do the same thing as calling `flush()` when the buffer is full.

So when should you call `flush()` manually ?

- When you need data to be on disk **now**. If you have a program which reads data from the file on disk at the same time it is written, you may want to ensure *all* of the data which is supposed to be on disk is *actually* there.
- If you are writing through a network connection, you may want to call `flush()` so that the data gets sent through the network immediately.

Usually it is *not* necessary to call `flush()`. Just write and call `close()` when finished, and no need for `flush()` as `close()` flushes the buffer for you.