# PrintWriter not printing text to file

Tags: java

I have an assignment to copy the text of one file to another. With the following code, I can print the lines of the file to the console, but it is not working to print to the output file.

```
      try {
        System.out.print("Enter the file name with extension : ");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        File inputFile = new File(input.nextLine());
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("/Users/jonathanzier/Dropbox/IdeaProjects/CSE_205_Homework1/src/com/company/output.txt");


        input = new Scanner(inputFile);


        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            out.println(input.nextLine());
           //System.out.println(input.nextLine());  - This will print 
           //correctly to the console
        }
        out.close();


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File Not Found");
    }
```

Comment: File Not Found error is shown

Comment: Try adding out.flush(); after  out.println(input.nextLine());

Comment: @iamsankalp89 it is your system. if file doesn't found, then he should see it.

Comment: @pavithraCS - Yes that worked, why is this? Thanks

Comment: I changed the path the dear

Comment: @iamsankalp89 I was not getting a file not found error.

Comment: No issue I will check it once again

Comment: for more info see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29991851/what-exactly-is-the-use-of-flush-for-a-printwriter-object

Comment: It works correctly now that I added out.flush() in the loop. Thanks!

Comment: @pavithraCS `out.close()` will flush but why it doesn't work if you don't explicitly mention it?

Comment: Consider using a try-with-resource clause or closing the PrintWriter in a finally clause. The way your try-catch statement is currently formatted, it you run into a FileNotFoundException, the clause will break and never close the PrintWriter.

Answer (score 0):

Print writer uses Buffered writer. It will not write to the disk immediately. When you invoke `println`, `printf`, or `format` methods, it will write to the disk if automatic flushing is enabled. Otherwise you have to invoke `flush` method to write to disk. Usually invoking `close` method should write the whatever in the buffer to the file without the need of `flush` method.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html