# how to store comma separated values in a String to CSV using java

Tags: java, arrays, file, export-to-csv

I want to store the string into CSV file using the following code but empty CSV is being generated.

Code

```
 try {
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("test.csv"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String str ="1 cup, honey, 2 tablespoons ,canola" ;
            sb.append(str);
            writer.write(String.valueOf(sb));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

> **Expected Output :**
>
> The data should show like this in CSV file.
>
> 1 cup
>
> honey
>
> 2 tablespoons
>
> canola

How I could get expected results.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
        String str ="1 cup, honey, 2 tablespoons ,canola" ;
```

This keeps the data in a single line and every comma takes the data to new column as per the rules of CSV file. You need to append a new line in your data to keep your data to new line after every comma. This can be done through this.

```
 try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("test.csv"))) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String str = "1 cup, honey, 2 tablespoons ,canola";
        String []splitted_str=str.split(",");
        for (String string : splitted_str) {
            sb.append(string).append("\n"); //this will add a new line after every value separated by comma.
        }
        writer.write(sb.toString());

        System.out.println("done!");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Actually, with this code you don't need to `close()` the writer (or even `flush()` it, for that matter).  - the `try-with-resources` you use does that for you.

Comment: @daniu thanks for sharing that. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to flush the writer content 
.
add 
`writer.flush()` after `writer.write()`

You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29991851/what-exactly-is-the-use-of-flush-for-a-printwriter-object/29992121)

and also remember to *close the writer* stream for resource optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Because I like short code:

```
String str = "1 cup, honey, 2 tablespoons ,canola";
try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("test.csv"))) {
    Arrays.stream(str.split(",")).map(String::trim).forEach(writer::println);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```